# PHP - Passing json_encode Array to jQuery changes format and type

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, google-visualization

**PHP Array Output** `print_R($color_str);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => '#ff0000','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4'
    [1] => '#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'
    [2] => '#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'
    [3] => '#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'
    [4] => '#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'
    [5] => '#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'
    [6] => '#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'
    [7] => '#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'
)
```

**Pass array to jQuery**

```
var color = new Array();
color = <?php echo json_encode($color_str) ?>;
```

`console.log(color);` outputs below

`["'#ff0000','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4'", "'#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'", "'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'", "'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'", "'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'", "'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'", "'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'", "'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'"]`

To access the array using key,

```
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

    var color_str = [color[i]];
    console.log(color_str); //prints  ["'#ff0000','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4'"]
    console.log(jQuery.type(color_str)); //prints array
}
```

The double quotes are creating issue and while replacing it, its type changes to string instead of `array`

```
var strReplace = color_str[i].replace(/\,/g, "','");
finalColorStr = "'" + strReplace + "'";
```

The `colors` param expect an array as input.

```
var options = {
                width: 700,
                height: 350,
                legend: {position: 'none'},
                bar: {groupWidth: '50%'},
                isStacked: true,
                colors: finalColorStr
            };
```

How do I alter the array value to change its format like below and maintaining the type `array` ?

```
["#ff0000", "#4caf50", "#4caf50", "#4caf50", "#00bcd4"]
```

Comment: In jquery, serialize your array or in php just again encode your array i.e json_encode($array);

Comment: Maybe `[0] => '#ff0000','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4'` must be `[0] => ['#ff0000', '#4caf50', '#4caf50', '#4caf50', '#00bcd4']`

Comment: Have you tried this representation in php: array(array(), array()...array()) and then use json_encode()

Comment: while you are creating the color array in php, why don't you assign the values as an array and then convert to json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// that's what you apparently have right now
$x = array(
    "'#ff0000','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4'",
    "'#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'",
    "'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'",
    "'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'",
    "'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'",
    "'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'",
    "'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'",
    "'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'"
);


$y = array_map( // for each "row" in $x
    function($e) {
        // get everything between ' as one respective element
        preg_match_all("!'([^']+)'!", $e, $m);
        return $m[1];
    },
    $x
);

echo json_encode($y);
```

that will give you an array of arrays like

```
[
  ["#ff0000", ..., "#00bcd4"],
  ["#00bcd4", ..., "#4caf50"],
  ...
]
```

But a better option would be not to start with

```
array(
  "'#ff0000','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4'",
  "'#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'"
  ..
)
```

anyway. But I don't know if you have a choice or not ....

Answer (score 0):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array('#ff0000','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4'),
    [1] => Array('#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'),
    [2] => Array('#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'),
    [3] => Array('#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'),
    [4] => Array('#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'),
    [5] => Array('#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'),
    [6] => Array('#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'),
    [7] => Array('#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50')
)
```